# When will KDE 4.8.3 land in Kubuntu 12.04 (official repository)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde4

When will KDE SC 4.8.3 be available in the Kubuntu 12.04 official repositories?

Answer (score 3):

It's already here, but you must enable the Kubuntu Backports PPA from Kubuntu to get it: [Plasma and KDE Applications 4.8.3 Updates](http://www.kubuntu.org/news/kde-sc-4.8.3)

Answer (score 1):

**Stable Release Updates**

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates:

> Once an Ubuntu release has been completed and published, updates for
>   it are only released under certain circumstances, and must follow a
>   special procedure called a "stable release update" or SRU.

**The Drill**

Kubuntu Updates PPA /1/ -> Ubuntu Proposed /2/ -> Ubuntu Updates /3/

**Status**

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates:

> There is an automatically generated list of packages which are
>   currently undergoing this process.

=> http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/pending-sru.html

**Maybe soon ?**

http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2012/05/25/%23kubuntu-devel.html

> ScottK    yofel: The last of the 4.8.3 stuff is accepted. 22:22

http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2012/05/27/%23kubuntu-devel.html

> Ezim  Hi when will 4.8.3 be avaible in official repo? 15:41
>
> Ezim  again sorry.... when will kde 4.8.3 16:20
>
> apachelogger  Ezim: once it was QA'd  16:41
>
> apachelogger  which takes aleast another 4 days   16:42

**Links**

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Kubuntu
2. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/EnableProposed
3. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

You can put this question to Kubuntu team.

To do this follow this [LINK](http://www.kubuntu.org/contact-us), with the Kubuntu contacts.

Or you can:

- Chat in Kubuntu IRC Channel;
- Web Forums;
- Mailing List;

Follow this [link](http://www.kubuntu.org/community).